# Which is the missing word?

Tags: word, english

```
A M O U N T 

I N P U T S 

A B S O R B

? ? ? ? ? ? 

A M U L E T

S I S T E R
```

**Which is the missing word to get the true answer?**

Note: There is only one English word that fits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a similar vein to Tom's answer, my guess is

> BLOWUP

As then you get

> ```
>   A M O U N T
>
>   I N P U T S
>
>   A B S O R B
>
>   B L O W U P
>
>   A M U L E T
>
>   S I S T E R
> ```

That is,

> Both of the words TRUE and ANSWER reading down and I think it's the only word that fits these criteria.

Comment: I really didn't expect a so fast correct answer, congratulations! I guess this community is better than my riddles :) @hexomino

Comment: Super answer. I was outwit(ted) but don't feel a nitwit as hexomino is back after giving some of us a chance :) Also nice question - no growls from me :)

Answer (score 7):

Is the answer

> ANSWER

Just for the reason

> ```
>   A M O U N T
>
>   I N P U T S
>
>   A B S O R B
>
>   A N S W E R
>
>   A M U L E T
>
>   S I S T E R
> ```

Comment: thought the same

Comment: @Tom that is not the true answer, but you are close! Take care of the note, there is only **ONE** English word that fits!

Comment: Clever. This is the best answer I guess

Comment: @D.Mellow - that makes it all the more intriguing. I will try and someone better can post the **one true** answer! :)